# How to name an inherited classes?

Tags: oop, inheritance, naming

Let's say I have inheritance like this

```
         Person
           |
     +-----+------+
     |            |
 Student       Teacher
```

Then I would call `Person` the *Base*.

How would I call `Student`?

*Inherited class* sounds stupid. Is there a single word for it?

Comment: Are you looking for derived class??

Comment: I don't know. Does not sound much better to me :)

Comment: Student is a "specialization" of Person if you want a single word.

Comment: what about subclass? student is subclass of person

Answer (score 1):

Basically using `Base` for super class, so: PersonBase 
And for it's implementations it's common to add `Impl` like: StudentImpl and TeacherImpl